# Httaccess redirect rule for a link with parentheses

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect urls such as "`example.com/example/(justsometext)/id-123`" into something more elegant like "`example.com/example/id-123`" so I want to get rid of parentheses. How can I do it in a way (justsometext) isn't considered as a % variable (%1)?

Thank you!
Romano

I searched for an answer everywhere but didn't manage to find any suitable solution.

Comment: A URL that contains a literal parenthesis is invalid. You'd have to percent encode those characters to code it as a valid path inside a URL. Most environments offer some form of a `url_encode(...)` function for that.

Comment: However it is unclear what you actually ask from your question. Please invest time into revising your question, there is an "edit" link below it, _use it_ . Try to read the question with our eyes, us knowing nothing about your setup. What is `$linkacross`? Is that also a literal part of the URL, or is that somehow substituted? Please try not to ask how you can achieve something the way you now _think_ you might be able to. But tell us exactly what data you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: arkascha, text inside the parentheses is irrelevant. It's just the way urls are made on the website whose urls I need to redirect. I have to redirect urls such as "example.com/example/(justsometext)/id-123" into something more elegant like "example.com/example/id-123" so I want to get rid of parentheses. I hope it's clear now! Thank you!

Comment: Now you removed the $ sign completely from your example URL, but you are still asking, _"How can I do it in a way it isn't considered as a $ variable?"_ - so is that still the actual question now, or not? And if it is - what problem exactly _is_ the $ sign giving you?

Comment: And in addition to what @CBroe asks: if you want to leave out that portion enclosed by those strange parentheses, then what should incoming requests of the form `/example/id-123` internally get rewritten to, to be responded to? The rewriting logic cannot somehow magically _guess_ what it should insert to reconstruct the form `/example/(justsometext)/id-123` ...

Comment: Sorry guys I am dumb. I didn't mean $ but %!!!!! I want the parentheses to be ignored and not be considered as "1%" in RewriteRule

Comment: They won't. A `RewriteRule` does not parse anything into a `%1` placeholder. A `RewriteCond` would. You can prevent that by escaping the literal parenthesis chars by a leading back slash char (`\`). I still fail to understand what you are trying to do, though ...

Comment: So you mean you do not want them to have their regular expression special meaning (_capturing_ of matched parts), but you just want them to be seen as literal characters - so you simply need to escape them, by putting a backslash in front of them. `(foo)` captures the `foo` part, `\(foo\)` matches the literal text `(foo)`.

Comment: I have the impression that you misunderstood how request rewriting works. You cannot use it to change links you send out on the fly. Request rewriting operates on _incoming_ requests.

Comment: Is `(justsometext)` always a whole path segment delimited by slashes?

Comment: MrWhite, yes sir and it containts a & symbol: ($linkacross)
CBroe: I tried it but it didn't work. I do something wrong I guess

Comment: "and it containts a & symbol: ($linkacross)" - Your example appears to contain a `$`? `&` or `$` or both?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this near the top of the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/\([^/]+\)(.*) /$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs later in the file, as I expect it does.)

Note that to match literal parentheses in the regex, they are backslash-escaped to negate their special meaning (as a *group* delimiter). ie. `\(` and `\)` respectively.

The backreferences `$1` and `$2` contain the parts of the URL-path that surround the part to be removed. ie. `$1` contains everything up to (but not including) the slash that precedes the parenthesised section.

This does, however, make various assumptions:

- There is always at least one path segment *before* the path segment that needs to be removed (ie. the one that contains `(justsometext)`). This satisfies your example: `/example/(justsometext)`.
- `justsometext` can be any characters enclosed in literal parentheses, except other slashes.
- `(justsometext)` occupies a complete path segment, prefixed with a slash.